# Correct way to create multiple-practitioner Google business page

Tags: google-plus-pages, google-my-business

I'm trying to understand Google's [Google Places quality guidelines](https://support.google.com/places/answer/107528).  I am currently the admin for the Google+ Business pages for a dental office.  The dental office page was created with the actual business name.  I would like to add the ability for people to find the individual dentists on Google Maps by searching their names.  Right now you have to search the business name and then go to the Google Plus profile to see the names.

I have read a lot about issues with duplicates ([see this discussion](http://marketing-blog.catalystemarketing.com/google-places-duplicates-doctor-dentist-lawyer.html)).  I'd like to be able to create separate pages so that each individual dentist could get reviews, post content, etc.  Then if the dentist were to leave, we could easily remove the page (or transfer it potentially for the dentist to their new location).

I am also trying to avoid individuals pages being marked as "Permanently closed" if one of the dentists leaves ([see this discussion](http://moz.com/community/q/do-practitioner-listings-for-the-same-business-need-to-have-different-categories)).  This appears to happen if a business page is created with the individuals name at the same location as the business itself.  Obviously this could potentially confuse customers if they see "Permanently Closed", they might assume the entire office is closed, even if its just that one dentist left.

Has anyone ever set this up?  I'd be curious how you did it to reduce or avoid the issues that I've read about.

Right now when you create a page, you have a few options for page type:

[image: screen shot]

- Local Business or Place
- Product or Brand
- Company, Institution or Organization
- Arts, Entertainment or Sports
- Other

I created the business page using `Local Business or Place`.  I also tried setting up an `Other` page with the dentists names, but this doesn't show in Google Maps when you search for it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't suppose you've checked out how other multi-practioner practices are doing it (or failing to do it)?

Comment: @AlEverett - It looks like most places I've seen set it up as multiple Google Local Business pages.  One with the business name, the others with either just the person name, or business name - person name, etc.  There doesn't seem to be any consistency and I'm not sure that way will allow the page to be easily deleted.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the individual dentists' pages to show up in places / local, you would need to divide the office building's address into separate "suites" so that each dentist appeared to have their own address. You could then move the dentist to their new location as necessary and or reassign their old suite to the new occupant. I think this would solve the whole range of problems you are describing.